# Only alow access to a file for logged in users in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, file, security

I have a service that puts a HTML file on my web server that should be accessed by logged on users only. I present this file on a specific page with an IFRAME. However this file is also available if one know the path to the file. Is there a way to lock down the file so that if a user tries https://example.com/path/file.html that will not get the file unless they are logged in?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can place .htaccess with restriction of direct access like that:
deny from all

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: By the way, you must create script, that checks if user logged in and if it true, include the html document you wants. In .htaccess you can add RewriteRule that points request to script out of this directory. Ask if u need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one folder for your file let say " filefolder ", and place your html file in this folder, so your url will be https://mydomain.com/filefolder/file.html

Now block user from accessing this file directly by url https://mydomain.com/filefolder/file.html you create .htaccess file inside your " filefolder " and in htaccess file add below line of code to block all user direct access to file

```
deny from all
```

Comment: That worked for closing access to the file in the folder from everybody also logged in users....